# ファイル一覧を更新日時でソートするこのプログラムを、もっと簡潔にできないか

Tags: c#

下のプログラムのような方法を検索しても古い記事しかでてきません。
もう少し新しいアルゴリズム、簡潔なものはありませんか？

```
// 二つのファイルの最終書き込み日時を取得して比較するメソッド
static int CompareLastWriteTime(string fileX, string fileY)
{
    return DateTime.Compare(File.GetLastWriteTime(fileX), File.GetLastWriteTime(fileY));
}

static void Main()
{
    // カレントディレクトリ直下にあるすべてのファイルを取得する
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(".");

    // 取得したすべてのファイルを最終書き込み日時順でソートする)
    Array.Sort(files, CompareLastWriteTime);

    // ソートした結果を表示
    foreach (string file in files) {
        // ファイル名と最終書き込み日時を表示
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", File.GetLastWriteTime(file), file);
    }
}
```

Comment: 他の人が読んでも理解出来る内容に修正しました。意図が間違っていたら戻しますのでお伝え下さい。

Comment: 尚、ファイルの更新日付順でソート出来ない件とアルゴリズムが新しい古いというのは関係ありません。

Comment: あれ、編集前の元の記事で、検索もソートもできていたはずですが・・・「もうちょっとマシ（？）な書き方は無いですか？」という意図の質問だと解釈し、それに対して回答しました。まめたろうさん、質問したかったことって、今の編集後の内容で合っているんですか？　だとすると私の回答は的外れですが・・・

Comment: 回答の承認もされていますし、mok2pokさんの仰る通りだと思いますので編集をロールバックし、その上でタイトルと本文を調整しました（これは余計かもしれませんが）。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「新しいアルゴリズム」は分かりませんが、「簡潔なもの」ならLINQを使うというのはどうですか？

```
static void Main()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(".").OrderBy(f => File.GetLastWriteTime(f));

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", File.GetLastWriteTime(file), file);
    }
}
```

Comment: この回答は編集前の質問に対するものです。編集後の今の質問には合っていません。